# dplyr arrange - sort groups by another column and then sort within each group

Tags: r, sorting, group-by, dplyr

I have a data frame as below

```
 Customer  OrderNo  Tot_Orders
 aaa       2        3
 aaa       1        3
 aaa       3        3
 bbb       1        1
 ccc       1        2
 ccc       2        2
```

I want to group by customer and then sort on Tot_Orders after which I want to sort on OrderNo within each customer group to get

```
 Customer  OrderNo  Tot_Orders
 bbb       1        1
 ccc       1        2
 ccc       2        2
 aaa       1        3
 aaa       2        3
 aaa       3        3
```

How can I use dplyr group_by and arrange for the same? I tried

```
 df %>% group_by(Customer) %>% arrange(Tot_Orders)
```

but this didn't help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the new example `df %>% arrange(Tot_Orders, OrderNo)` gives the expected result as showed and then you may do the `group_by`.  But, this may again be a simple example..   This also gave the expected result for the previous example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  arrange(Tot_Orders, OrderNo) %>% 
  group_by(Customer)
#   Customer OrderNo Tot_Orders
#1      ccc       1          1
#2      bbb       1          2
#3      bbb       2          2
#4      aaa       1          3
#5      aaa       2          3
#6      aaa       3          3

df1 %>%
    arrange(Tot_Orders, OrderNo) %>% 
    group_by(Customer)
#    Customer OrderNo Tot_Orders
#1      bbb       1          1
#2      ccc       1          2
#3      ccc       2          2
#4      aaa       1          3
#5      aaa       2          3
#6      aaa       3          3
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Customer = c("aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "bbb", "bbb", 
"ccc"), OrderNo = c(2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L), Tot_Orders = c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L)), .Names = c("Customer", "OrderNo", "Tot_Orders"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

df1 <- structure(list(Customer = c("aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", 
"ccc"), OrderNo = c(2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L), Tot_Orders = c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L)), .Names = c("Customer", "OrderNo", "Tot_Orders"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but this doesn't seem to work. This looks like a simple sort on Customer. Instead, I want to sort Customer group on column Tot_Orders. I've changed the example in the original question to make it more clear.